# Can I stop my male cat from beating up my female cat?

Tags: cats, behavior

One morning my grandson and I found a cat digging through our trash can. He was literally skin and bones. We decided to fees him. His need for food over powered his fear of us and he let us pet him. Soon we had him in the house. You could tell he'd never been pet or picked up or in a house before. I noticed that his only animal friends were dogs. The other cats that were around he would fight with.
We got him fixed and named him McMouzer. He is a little over a year old. He is a country car, heavy pawed and can tear his way out of a cardboard cat carrier in no time at all.
We moved in with my mother and my 11 year old female snowshoe named Stella lives there. As soon as McMouzer laid eyes on her he was after her and it hasn't stopped . When he sees her he's after her. He looks for her. If he sees her through the window he jumps at the window trying to get her.
How can I stop him from beating up on Stella?

Comment: How long has it been since he was castrated? It takes quite a while for testosterone madness to abate, sometimes. Whether, and how soon, it will abate is very much an individual thing though: if it's been months, it will probably be many more months if ever, but if it's been just a few days or a week, give it a month or so. Obviously it's a good idea to keep them apart for now, if possible.